# Can we have variables name in html, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following structure

```
<tr>
    <td data-unit="spear" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="spear-1" />
    </td>
    <td data-unit="sword" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="sword-1" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want every time i call clone function by jQuery variable in name should automatically increment like `spear-2. sword-2`

this is an example, i have 20 feilds like that and i want a generic thing which can change this for all

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show the code, How you are cloning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple example code like so :

**Html**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td data-unit="spear" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="spear" />
    </td>
    <td data-unit="sword" class="tooltip">
        <input type="text" size="2" name="sword" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="knife" />
        <select name="book">
            <option>as</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<button>click</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var a = 0;
  $('button').click(function () {
    a++;
    var tr = $('tr').first().clone();

    // inside find(), put any element you want to increment
    // eg : .find('input, select, textarea')

    $(tr).find('input, select').attr('name', function(i, e){

        // i => index
        // e => old value
        // a => custom increment value
        return e+'-' + a;
    });
    $(tr).appendTo('table');
 })
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/1czkjgd0/4/)** - Inspect Element(chrome) to see the attribute name changed for newly cloned element.

Comment: is this not renaming `sword` to `spear-*` ??

Comment: this is an example, i have 20 feilds like that and i want a generic thing which can change this for all

Answer (score 0):

This Jquery code can help you to clone HTML Elements with different ID`s

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var i = 2
            $("#btnClone").click(function () {
                $("#SpearClone").html($("#SpearClone").html() + '<input type="text" size="2" name="spear-' + i + '" />');
                $("#SwordClone").html($("#SwordClone").html() + '<input type="text" size="2" name="sword-' + i + '" />');
                i++;
            });

        });
    </script>

<div id="DivClone">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td data-unit="spear" class="tooltip" id="SpearClone">
                    <input type="text" size="2" name="spear-1" />
                </td>
                <td data-unit="sword" class="tooltip" id="SwordClone">
                    <input type="text" size="2" name="sword-1" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" id="btnClone" value="Call Clone" />
    </div>
```

I hope I helped you...
Regards ;)